# Where is safari cache folder in Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, safari

I want to search for some cached MP3 files in the cache folder but cannot find it... I've searched online for 10mins but the result I got is all about how to clear cache. I want to know where is the cache folder of Safari in Mountain Lion...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

The cache is here:

```
/Users/<userid>/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
```

But the only thing you're likely to find there is a `Cache.db` file.
If you're comfortable with databases, that's a SQLite3 file you can open with `sqlite3`, which ships with your mac.

But in my quick tests, it doesn't look like it caches external files like MP3.

You might want to try [SafariCacheExplorer](http://www.beecubu.com/desktop-apps/SafariCacheExplorer/). Not free; but the demo (good for 5 uses) very nicely enumerated my cache. No mp3 files, though.